# how can I count and remove certain lines with condition in a CSV file?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a CSV file looks like this:

```
id,country
12343,China
23455,Japan
47,Singapore
374,Australia
6572e,United Kingdom
```

- Firstly I want to count the total number of lines whose column
  id length is greater than 3
- Next I want to remove the lines whose id length is not equal
  to 5, and whose id contains an alphabetic character
- Finally I want to create a new file to store the result

I have tried awk method but I get this result:

```
mylaptop@MacBook-Pro ~ % awk 'length($1)!=19 {c++} END {print c+0}' myfile
quote>
```

If I type the command like this:

```
mylaptop@MacBook-Pro ~ % awk 'length($1)!=19 {c++} END {print c+0}' <myfile>
```

It will show:

```
zsh: parse error near `\n'
```

The expected output should be like in the Mac terminal:

```
mylaptop@MacBook-Pro ~ % awk 'length($1)!=19 {c++} END {print c+0}' myfile
4
```

and save all the changes in a file.

I am new to linux, so can you show the full commands for 3 questions?

Comment: Edit your question and add what you tried and where it went wrong. Also, add clarity regarding what you want to do. You state that you want to count the values under `column id` that have more than three characters but then you want to remove the lines where the number if characters is not equal to five. Which one do you want? Add the expected output to your question to clarify this.

Comment: Also, "not equal to 5 and containing character". Do you mean containing a non-numeric character, like "123q5" ? I note your input data contains a value which *is* length 5 and contains **e** -- what does that do ? Do you want the two conditions to be *and* or *or* ?

Comment: By the way, it is not CSV, it appears to be tab-separated.

Comment: @NasirRiley I have use a awk command like the answer below, but it doesn't show the result. It shows 'quote>'. I don't know what happened. Does it have something to do with my laptop? I am using a Mac.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant this two condition is 'and'

Comment: Like I said, add that and your expected output to your question so that it doesn't get lost in the comments. Also add to your question that you are using `awk` for MacOS and not the `gnu awk` or `gawk`.

Comment: @NasirRiley already done so! Thank you for your input!

Comment: The expected output doesn't appear anywhere in your question so no one has any idea as to what you need. You need to post an example of exactly what you need and not just a vague description.

Comment: @NasirRiley already done it. Can you help me with the problem? I don' t know why my code doesn't give a result.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to a MacBook or the MacOS `awk` so you'll have to wait for input from someone who does. I was simply trying to get you to specify exactly what you need and what you had done and where it wasn't working so that someone else can help you.

Comment: Did you actually type `<myfile>` ? That was probably intended to be a placeholder where you enter your own file name. The <myfile looks like an input redirection, and the > looks like an output redirection with a missing filename. That is probably why it complains about getting a newline at that point.

Comment: Why does your question mention 3 and 5, but your code says 19? Why should that work?

Comment: This code is simple awk -- Mac awk should be identical to GNU/awk here because no extensions are required.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like homework!

Count lines where length of column 1 is greater than 3

```
awk 'length($1)>3 {c++} END {print c+0}'
```

Discard lines where length of column 1 is not 5

```
awk 'length($1)==5'
```

Discard lines where length of column 1 is not 5 and it contains a non digit

```
awk 'length($1)==5 && $1 !~ /[^0-9]/'
```

Use the shell to direct the output to the new file.

Edit:
The file originally appeared to be a tab separated file, now it has been edited to be a CSV. This means the solutions need to be

```
awk -F, 'length($1)>3 {c++} END {print c+0}'
awk -F, 'length($1)==5'
awk -F, 'length($1)==5 && $1 !~ /[^0-9]/'
```

Comment: thank you so much! I have a qustion about using the awk commands. After I type in the command, it doesn't give the output, it will display a 'quote>' instead of the result. Why will it happen?

Comment: I have updated my question. Why won't I get the result?

Comment: @YKILYCHAN  `>` in a shell prompt is normally PS2 (secondary prompt). I don't know MacBook or zsh, but if it prompts with `quote>` I would guess it is asking for a continuation line because you have an unpaired quote in a previous line.

Comment: @YKILYCHAN I would guess you aren't providing the input file name on the command line and are running `awk 'script'` instead of `awk 'script' file` so awk is waiting for you to type some lines of input.

Comment: zsh promts you with `quote>` if you are inside a single quoted string. Make sure that you use the same character to start and finish your awk program, usually the single quote in the lower right of the keyboard rather than say the backquote.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of lines whose first comma-delimited field is longer than three characters, delete the header and any line whose first field is not four characters long or longer, then count the remaining lines.

```bsh
sed -e '1d' -e '/^[^,]\{4,\},/!d' file | wc -l
```

The `d` command deletes the line addressed by the preceding address (either a line number or a regular expression). If the preceding condition is not fulfilled,  `!d` triggers the deletion.

The expression `^[^,]\{4,\},` matches four or more non-commas at the start of the line, followed by a comma.

Remove all lines whose first field is not precisely five digits long while retaining the header and saving the result to a new file.

```bsh
sed -e '1b' -e '/^[[:digit:]]\{5\},/!d' file >newfile
```

We use the `b` command to branch to the end of the script for the first input line, skipping forward to the next cycle. Doing this ensures that the header line is printed rather than deleted.

The expression `^[[:digit:]]\{5\},` matches exactly five digits at the start of the line, followed by a comma.